# Understanding Goldstine theorem

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

I have read in Book An introduction to Banach space theory by Robert Megginson

**Theorem**
Goldstine's Theorem
Let $X$ be a normed space and let $Q$ be the natural map from $X$ into $X^{**}.$ Then $Q(B_X)$ is weakly* dense in $B_{X^{**}}.$

**Corollary**
Let $X$ be a normed space and let $Q$ be the natural map from $X$ into $X^{**}.$ Then $\overline{Q(B_X)}^{w^*} = B_{X^{**}}.$

**Corollary**
Let $X$ be a normed space and let $Q$ be the natural map from $X$ into $X^{**}.$ Then $Q(X)$ is weakly* dense in $X^{**}.$

My question
Q1 In fact i want to make sure of something. The statement that $Q(B_X)$ is weakly* dense in $B_{X^{**}}$ is different from the statement $\overline{Q(B_X)}^{w^*} = B_{X^{**}}.$

I think the statement that $Q(B_X)$ is weakly* dense in $B_{X^{**}}$ means for every element $x^{**}$ $\in$ $B_{X^{**}}$ there exists a net $(Q(x_n))$ in $Q(B_X)$ s.t. $Q(x_n)$ converges weakly* to $x^{**}.$ This means that we prove only that $B_{X^{**}} \subseteq \overline{Q(B_X)}^{w^*}.$ And that differs from that the two sides equals $\overline{Q(B_X)}^{w^*} = B_{X^{**}}.$ Is that true???

Q2 Can we say also that $\overline{Q(X)}^{w^*}$ = $X^{**}$ ??